How entity classes are created in large enterprise projects in spring boot?
How entity classes are created in large enterprise projects in spring boot?
IS it manually creating entity classes and define relationship for each classes ?
I was doing by manually creating the entity class but wondering how this is possible when there are many tables and complex relations

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
